# Connect Google Plus with Parse in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-plus, instagram-api, linkedin-api

In my android app, I want to link an existing Parse User with their Google Plus and Instagram accounts.

I looked at the Parse documentation on "Adding third-party authentication to your Web app" page but am not clear on how to do it.

https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app

Facebook and Twitter Integration for existing Parse User were very easy since they gave SDK :-) There doesnt seem to be such a library from parse for Instagram, LinkedIn and Google+ - which are all the 3 things remaining that I need to do.

appreciate any help.

Comment: Try firebase instead of parse

Answer (score 1):

Parse will be shutdown from next year, better to go for any other BaaS or use Amazon or Google cloud. Prepare your migration now rather than waiting for Parse to shutdown and re-invest your investigation on other cloud.